# Drawing a speech bubble

Tags: android, canvas, path

I tried to draw speech bubble in Android canvas using following code,

```
private void drawBubble() {
    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
    float percentage20 = bounds.height() * (20.0f / 100.0f);
    path.lineTo(bounds.left + percentage20, bounds.bottom - percentage20);
    RectF arcRect = new RectF(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.right, bounds.bottom - percentage20);
    path.addArc(arcRect, 130, 330);
    path.lineTo(bounds.left, bounds.bottom);
}
```

But this gives me following output.

[image]

As you see in this image I can't connect the line with bubble. Can someone redirects me in right path?

**Update**
I changed `addArc` to `arcTo`, Now my output is,

[image]

Comment: Why not simply using a 9 patch, a VectorDrawable or an SVG, instead?

Comment: @Phantômaxx, As I'm working on a drawing module, all my shapes belong to Path class only, So it would be better to maintain the code as much as simple if this one also in Path.

Comment: Then my approach would be: start with the interrupted ellipse (the **start** point will also be the **end** point). This means that when you stop drawing the ellipse to start the "stem" lines, you already know which is the end point (if I do remeber well, you can also draw a **closed** path by simply having an array of points through which it has to pass).